# How to avoid lost styles in browser recorded inputs

Tags: css, browser

[image: input form]

I have a custom input with my own css styles, but when the browser complete the recorded info for that fields , the styles lost

Answer (score 0):

Work on

```
::focus
```

element too.. i hope it will work.